# CSS, JQuery - Flex elements do not appear after display: none;

Tags: jquery, html, css, flexbox

You can view a working demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/hh8dhvqx/1/)

I have the following layout:

```
<div class="holder">
  <div id="container">
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Where the styling is as follows:

```
.holder{
    height: 200px;
    background: #0F0;
}
#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row;
  height: 200px;
  background: #00F;
}
.left {
  background: tomato;
  width: 25%;
}
.right {
  flex: 1;
  background: gold;
}
```

This means that:

- If `#container` is not visible, you should see the green background of `.holder`
- If either `.left` or `.right` do not display properly, you should see the blue background of `#container`

What you should see, on load, is this:

[image: Proper Flex Layout]

BUT! When I set `#container` to `display: none;`

```
$('#container').css('display', 'none');
```

and then reverse the process

```
$('#container').css('display', 'block');
```

the flex components do not display properly, and you only get:

[image: Incorrect flex layout]

What is happening? Why doesn't it display properly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change the container back to `display: flex` rather than `display: block`

Comment: Yep, beat you to the punch though. Realized what was happening right after I posted.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out right after I posted it, but I'll leave up for anyone who gets this problem in the future.

Should instead be:

```
$('#container').css('display', 'flex');
```

Just that easy.

View [here](https://jsfiddle.net/hh8dhvqx/3/)